# history.push not re-rendering the route in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I am changing route by push method of history, no re render is happening
from
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/104?patientView=true.
to.
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/104

By using history.push method

I can't put the actual but partially it look like this. index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './common/CreateBrowserHistory';
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history} onUpdate={() => handleUpdate()}>
     <App>
          <Route exact path={routeUrl+"/"} component={Auth0Login} />
          <Route exact path={routeUrl+"/dashboard"} />
  </Router>
 </Provider>
, document.querySelector('.appcontainer'));
```

An on dasboard.js which has route http://localhost:3000/dashboard/104?patientView=true.

on click

I am doing

```
history.push('/dashboard/104')
```

from a util.js file

Comment: please post some code for understanding your problem

Comment: Can you please put some of your route code on how do you arrange all the routing

Comment: I think You didn't get props at component, you need to send props from route please check to console your props in your component.

Comment: Please share your route code.

Comment: in my code redirection done by a file called util.js

Comment: Where is your onclick code and your CreateBrowserHistory code? Make sure you're not accidentally calling window.history. What is `routeUrl`? The router already has a concept of basePath and this is not how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the url format is same, so react wont rerender itself, for this you have to implement with your own code.  As per you, url is

> /dashboard/104

but url is

> /dashboard/:id

or similar to above

You can implement rerender using below code in the component for above link

```
 componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
        this.id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        })
        // fetch the new dashboard detail based and set it to the state of the component
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ... Its not about how to handle the change ... question is about how to trigger re-render .. so that componentDidUpdate trigger again..

Comment: The rerender takes place when some state is changed, so you can change some state or do .  this.setState({...this.state})

Comment: PS componentDidUpdate will always trigger in any props change, all you need to do is to check is the new specific props (id in above case) similar to the old one

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your route like this

```
<Route path={routeUrl+"/dashboard/:id"} component={Dashboard} />
```

If you use **`React DevTools`** you can see the changes for this two url.

For `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/104?patientView=true`

you will see **`search`** value like `search="?pagelife=true"` under `props.location`

and for `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/104` url **`search`** will be empty

And you will get the changes in **`componentDidUpdate`**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update: ", this.props.location);
  }
```

**Update**

Here is my sample code

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home";
import Page2 from "./page2";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div id="container">
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link>
          </div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/page2/:id" component={Page2} />
            <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and **Page2** class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Page2 extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount: ", this.props.location);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update: ", this.props.location.search);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>page 2</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push("/page2/2?page=true");
          }}
        >
          Query String
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push("/page2/2");
          }}
        >
          No Query String
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page2;
```